# My async actions are all same , carbon copy , is there generic action pattern?

Tags: generics, redux, action

My redux async actions are all same .
Only change is 'LOAD_TODOS_REQUEST', 'LOAD_TODOS_SUCCESS', 'LOAD_TODOS_FAILURE' kind oftypes and the endpoint .

Is there extension or a generic pattern , that I send endpoint as param and I only deal with reducers catching auto generated 'LOAD_XX_REQUEST', 'LOAD_XX_SUCCESS', 'LOAD_XX_FAILURE'.

Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you find that your reducers behave exactly the same for multiple endpoints, my first attempt would be to have **one** generic async action that fetches data, making the actual endpoint part of the action's payload:

```
const loadEndpoint = (endpoint, toDispatchOnSuccess) => (dispatch) => {
    // pass endpoint so that for example a loading indicator could state what exactly is being fetched.
    dispatch(loadEndpointRequest(endpoint));

    return httpClientOfYourChoice.get(endpoint)
        .then((data) => {
            dispatch(loadEndpointSuccess(endpoint, data));

            // If the data needs to go to a specific, other reducer in the end,
            // this action could be something like 'TODOS_RECEIVE' that puts the
            // data in state.todos.items, or something like that.
            dispatch(toDispatchOnSuccess(data));
        })
        .catch((error) => dispatch(loadEndpointFailure(endpoint, error)));
};
```

(sending endpoint as param as you said).

If that is not viable for some reason, you could look into some github projects that come up if you google "redux rest", "redux api client", "redux endpoint boilerplate" etc..

Be aware though that the reducer loses specificity. If two endpoints are being fetched at the same time, how do you display potential errors? Introduce a mapping of endpoint to last occured error?

While it is boring boilerplate to implement the same async action pattern over and over, it usually doesn't take very long and the simplicity it guarantees might pay off in the long run. Going fully generic and automated can introduce fun, new problems.

Comment: Thanks timotgl ,
This really looks like what is in my mind , I am going to try to implement it.
I have to modify your snipet so it can generate  custom types,  for example 
in  " dispatch(loadEndpointSuccess(endpoint, data , "TYPE_endpoint_SUCCESS")); "
so loadEndpointSuccess could return that type for the reducer to handle it accordingly.
Do you think it is also possible. I am new to redux/js sometimes i can't anticipate the limits.

Comment: I think it would be cleaner to dispatch another action. `loadEndpointSuccess` is in charge of closing the request lifecycle (every ongoing request must end with a success or failure action), while `toDispatchOnSuccess` is in charge of offloading the data you received and putting it in the right place.

Comment: now I understand the logic , 'toDispatchOnSuccess' will be my param also as my success action. What I had on my mind was something like;

`const loadEndpointSuccess = (endpoint,datat) => {
    return { 
      type: 'LOAD_'+endpoint.toUpperCase()+'_SUCCESS', 
      data
  } 
}` 

So when called " dispatch(loadEndpointSuccess(endpoint, data)); "
it will trigger right part at the reducer. 
Why should I dispatch "loadEndpointSuccess" if I skip it , it stil works.
I make it work by the way thank you again.

By using this method do I by pass using redux-thunk ?

Comment: Yes I wrote it in the thunk style, so you would need that as a middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, we used that lib in our previous project.
https://github.com/kolodny/redux-await

Comment: Thanks , i guess this considers  i use react , all the solutions a like assumes this , but i use Polymer